# Cache ParitalView on IE8&9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, partial-views

I use JqueryUI for showing my content and use Asp.net MVC partialview to render contnet of each tab item.

When I browse my site using Firefox or Chrome all thing is Ok , but when I use IE ,it seems that IE cache content of each tab.

For eaxample I had a tab that contains information about contact address and user can add new contact information , when user click on "Save" button in tab ,page sumbit data to server and page refreshed but tab dosen't refresh.

This problem exist only on IE .

Anyone can suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cache

You could disable caching on tabs as follows:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cache: false});
```

Regards,
Kiran Banda

Comment: according to this documnet , the default is false .But I set this option ,but error still exit .Only in IE I have this problem.

Comment: [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult YourMethod()